# grails render a list in select after ajax call by remote function

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I am using grails 2.1.1. I have a select box where on change i am calling an action by remothFunction to update another select. The list is populating in the controller but it's not rendering in the desired select box. Can anybody please help me on this please ? Here are my codes below :

my view page with two select and remote function >>>

```
 <html>
<head>
    <title>Render District & Thana</title>

    <g:javascript plugin="jquery" library="jquery" src="jquery/jquery-1.8.0.js" />

    <script>
        function loadThana(districtId) {
            <g:remoteFunction controller="greeting" action="loadThanaByDistrict" update="thanaId" params="'districtId='+districtId"/>
        }
    </script>

</head>

<body>
<g:form controller="greeting" action="renderDistrictThana">
   Select District : <g:select
            name="districtId"
            id="districtId"
            from="${district}"
            optionKey="id"
            optionValue="districtName"
            noSelection="['null':'Select District']"
            onchange="loadThana(this.value)"/><br/>


   Select Thana : <g:select
            name="thanaId"
            id="thanaId"
            from="${thana}"
            optionKey="id"
            optionValue="thanaName"
            noSelection="['null':'Select Thana']"/><br/>

    <g:submitButton name="submit" id="submit" value="Render Distric & Thana"/>
</g:form>
</body>
</html>
```

my action for render the list in 2nd combo >>>

```
def loadThanaByDistrict() {
    def district = District.get(params.districtId?.toLong())
    def thana = Thana.findAllByDistrict(district)

    render thana
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller might be look like as below,

```
def loadThanaByDistrict(){
    def district = District.get(params.districtId?.toLong())
    def thana = Thana.createCriteria().list{eq('district',district)}
    String options
    thana.each{ options += "<option value='"+[replace it with your expected field]+"'>"+[replace it with your expected field]+"</option>"
    render options
}
```

I hope it'll work fine.

Comment: it works fine. But is there any way to load the list in the combo thanaId instead of overwrite it ???!!!